# How do you make cogs in interactions.py?

Tags: discord, interaction

How would one make cogs like in discord.py, but in interactions.py?

I basically want to have a seperate python file for each command, and let them all being loaded in main.py... but I don't know what you need in the in the python files with the actual commands.

Answer (score 0):

We use `Extension` for that. Here is an example of using `Extension`, a.k.a Cogs, in discord.py.

Bot main file:

```py
import interactions

client = interactions.Client(...)

client.load("ext1")

client.command(
    name="command_outside",
    description"This command is in main bot file",
)
async def _command_outside(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
    await ctx.send("This command is ran outside of Extension.")

client.start()
```

ext1.py file, which is the Extension, a.k.a Cogs.

```py
import interactions

class Ext(interactions.Extension):
    def __init__(self, client: interactions.Client) -> None:
        self.client: interactions.Client = client

    @interactions.extension_command(
        name="command_in_ext",
        description"This command is in an Extension",
    )
    async def _ext_command(self, ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
        await ctx.send("This command is ran inside an Extension")

def setup(client):
    Ext(client)
```

Do notice that you need to change the command decorator, since stuffs like `@client.command()` or `@client.component()` will not work in Extension.

You can have a look at the docs [here](https://interactionspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=extension#is-there-something-like-cogs).